# Invertible Conditions in Polynomial Rings

Tags: ring-theory, inverse-function

Let ${\bf a}(x)\in (\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})[x]$, where $q$ is a prime. Suppose that
${\bf a}(1)\equiv 0\pmod{q}$.

*Question:* How to show that ${\bf a}(x)$ is not invertible in $\frac{\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}}{x^N-1}$ where $N$ is prime.

*try:* Using assumptions we get $(x-1)\mid {\bf a}(x)$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})[x]$.

But I don't know how to continue the proof.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $x-1\mid a(x)$.

On the other hand, $x-1\mid x^N-1$ and so the gcd between $a(x)$ and $x^N-1$ is a multiple of $x-1$.

It follows that $a(x)$ is not invertible in the quotient ring $\Bbb Z_q[x]/\langle x^N-1\rangle$, since the invertible elements in this ring have $gcd(a(x),x^N-1)= 1$. All other elements are zero divisors (bar $0$ which is absorbing).

Let $gcd(a(x),x^N-1)=d$.
Then the extended Euclidean algorithm gives $d = c(x)(x^N-1) + b(x)a(x)$.

If $d=1$, then $b(x)$ will be the inverse of $a(x)$ in the quotient ring.

The situation in $\Bbb Z_n$ is similar.

Comment: See explanation the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your full explanation.